# Broken admin grid after patch

Tags: admin, grid, patches

I've just applied the last 5 security patches to a client's site and now some of their 3rd party modules are misbehaving in the admin dashboard. I've fixed most of them but 2 in particular are vexing me.
Magestore PDF Invoice Plus and FME Percentage Pricing
When I click on the "Manage Templates" link (for PDF Plus) and "Manage Rules" (for Percentage Pricing) in the menu I get a screen with no content. The header, menu and footer are loading, there's no PHP errors and there's no grid.

The customer's support period has run out and he doesn't want to buy the extensions again. Any ideas on how to fix the blank grids?

Comment: patch number ?  if you have some files in `app/code/local/Mage` this could be your problem

Comment: To me it sounds like patch 6788 related. Did you enable the patch 6788 under system > configuration > admin > security ?

Comment: I have "Admin routing compatibility mode for extensions" set to Enabled. Disabling it breaks too many menu links.

Comment: @DenialDesign yes but you need to fix your extensions to be able to disable it that's the main point of the 6788 patch. Keeping it enabled means the patch is not applied and your store is vulnerable to a shoplift attack. I suggest you enable the patch and fix your extensions first

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have applied SUPEE-7405 a potential cause of a white screen in the admin panel would be if the site is running on PHP 5.3. The changes to `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Helper/Sales.php` introduce an incompatibility with PHP 5.3. Near the top of `escapeHtmlWithLinks` it declares `$links = [];`, this will need changing to `$links = array();`.

Comment: Good idea but as it seems only related to third party modules I highly doubt it

Comment: It would largely depend on what functionality the third party modules provide. The helper method affected could well be called from third party extensions. Isolating the exact issue will be difficult given that you've applied 5 patches at the same time. It could be any change from those files. Temporarily editing index.php to put the store in developer mode might at least yield an error to debug. To do that remove the if statement wrapping `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);`.

Comment: @PeterO'Callaghan The site is indeed running on PHP 5.3 and I had to change `$links = [];` to `$links = array();`
I'm not getting a white screen though, I'm getting a blank admin page. The header and footer and menu are loading fine, just no content.
Developer mode didn't reveal any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify their layout XML accordingly to the namespace change?

E.g. from `<company_module_admin_grid>` to `<admin_company_module_grid>`.

It should somewhat match the request URL pattern

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the extensions and that fixed the problem.